# npmで存在しないファイルを指し、エラーがでる。

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm

ビルドツールのgulpを使っているのですが、存在しないファイルをさし、エラーがでてしまいます。

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
CssSyntaxError: /Volumes/project/main.scss:5:4: Unknown word

// bower:scss
   ^
```

（このプロジェクトではmainという名前のscssは存在しないですが）cacheかな？と思い
npm cache cleanをしても解消されず。。

```
npm cache clean && sudo npm cache clean -g
```

以前も、なぜか別プロジェクトのファイルを読み込もうとし、存在しないよ。とエラーが出ました。
（その時はパスが完全に別のプロジェクト名だったので気がつきました。）

今回も前回も、Macを再起動したら治りましたが、これに躓くたびに再起動は少々厳しく、、
nodeを理解しきれてないのも問題なのかと思いますが、こういった現象の対処策など
ご存知でしたら教えていただけますと幸いです。

Comment: gulpfileの中身も載せたほうがよいと思います。

Comment: すみません、すごく時間が経ってしまいましたが、二進も三進も行かなかったのでgulpfileは作り直しました。。